# Importing subversion repository into pre-existing repository?

Tags: svn

We are moving a software project repository in-house from a vendor that is maintaining our code.  I know how to do an `svnrdump` to get the revision history, but in all the online documents I've seen, everyone is always talking about importing into a *new* repository.  We have a local subversion repository, with its own version numbers.

Is using `svnadmin load` going to work with renumbering the version numbers?  If not, is there a way to cleanly do this?

Comment: Sure that works. The dump is nothing but a series of commits. You can commit them into any repository, not just an empty one. The only thing that may cause problems: name collisions. But I don't see why you don't simply make a test: dump your in-house repository, build a new one from that. In there you can make as many import attempts as you like and check the outcome. No risk at all!

Comment: @arkascha if you make that the answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Ok, put that into a separate answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure that works. The dump is nothing but a series of commits. You can commit them into any repository, not just an empty one. The only thing that may cause problems: name collisions. But I don't see why you don't simply make a test: dump your in-house repository, build a new one from that. In there you can make as many import attempts as you like and check the outcome. No risk at all!